# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'codedata.pkl'

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, pickle

This is a school program to learn how to use file and directory in Python. So to do my best I create a function to open, set it as a variable and close properly my file.

But I got the error of the title:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'codedata.pkl'

```
def load_db():
""" load data base properly 
And get ready for later use

Return:
-------
    cd : (list) list of tuples
"""

file = open('codedata.pkl', 'rb')
codedata = pickle.loads(file)
file.close()

return codedata
```

From the interpreter, this is the line

```
file = open('codedata.pkl', 'rb')
```

Which is the problem, but I don't see where is the source of the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So let me ask a stupid question: does the file `codedata.pkl` exist?

Comment: what do you mean ? 
I earn that python open the file and if it doesn't exit it create it
is that wrong ?
And if yes how can I check if the file exist and create it ?

Comment: That is wrong. `'rb'` tells Python to open the file for **r**eading (in **b**inary mode). If there's nothing to read, it fails.

Comment: ok I put just  'r'  and it tells me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check what is the location of the file?

If your file is located at `/Users/abc/Desktop/`, then the code to open the file on python would be as shown below

```
file = open('/Users/abc/Desktop/codedata.pkl', 'rb')
codedata = pickle.load(file)
file.close()
```

You can also check if the file exists at the desired path by doing something like this

```
import os
filepath = '/Users/abc/Desktop/codedata.pkl'
if os.path.exists(filepath):
    file = open('/Users/abc/Desktop/codedata.pkl', 'rb')
    codedata = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
else:
    print("File not present at desired location")
```

Answer (score 0):

it happens when you run the script without determining it's the current working directory (example in vs code if you go to Explorer Tape )
You do not work from the same directory that your data.pkl in  that's why No file exists

[image]

You can know the current directory from getcwd() usually it will be the C/User/.

```
print(os.getcwd())
filepath=""
if os.path.exists(r"D:\research\StleGAN\karras2019stylegan-ffhq-1024x1024.pkl"):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

The solution is to open a directory that contains the script or to add the full path.